# Is there a way to target all classes in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is is possible to write css rules to select and style all elements with non-empty class attributes?

Lets say I have 2 different paragraphs or headers with different classes. For example, h1 has a class of "id1" and h2 has a class of "id2".
How can I style them both?

Thank you.

Comment: "select to style all classes at once despite their different class names" makes no sense. Are you asking how to select all elements? Or all elements that have a non-empty class attribute, or all header tags which have a class attribute, or all header tags which have classes of `id1` or `id2`? Please clarify, because the answer is completely different in each case.

Answer (score 4):

you may use:

```
 .id1, .id2{
    //your css here
  }
```

Or if you mean all elements which have a `class` attribute, then you may use:

```
 *[class]{
    //your css
 }
```

But the above, also selects elements with an empty `class` such as:

```
<h1 class></h1>
```

or

```
<h1 class=""></h1>
```

to exclude such exceptions, you can modify the selector to:

```
*[class]:not([class=""])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute selector like this:

```css
[class] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quam praesentium alias recusandae tempora perspiciatis molestias accusamus ad in fuga, officiis id voluptate, quasi, rem inventore, illum sint voluptatem. Dolor.</p>

<p class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quam praesentium alias recusandae tempora perspiciatis molestias accusamus ad in fuga, officiis id voluptate, quasi, rem inventore, illum sint voluptatem. Dolor.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quam praesentium alias recusandae tempora perspiciatis molestias accusamus ad in fuga, officiis id voluptate, quasi, rem inventore, illum sint voluptatem. Dolor.</p>
```

```css
h1[class] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quam praesentium alias recusandae tempora perspiciatis molestias accusamus ad in fuga, officiis id voluptate, quasi, rem inventore, illum sint voluptatem. Dolor.</p>

<h1 class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quam praesentium alias recusandae tempora perspiciatis molestias accusamus ad in fuga, officiis id voluptate, quasi, rem inventore, illum sint voluptatem. Dolor.</p>

<h2 class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quam praesentium alias recusandae tempora perspiciatis molestias accusamus ad in fuga, officiis id voluptate, quasi, rem inventore, illum sint voluptatem. Dolor.</p>
```